# how to use canvas.SetLeft on DateTime in wpf

Tags: wpf

`Sesaonallist` is an `ObservableCollection` of type `DataPoint`.

I am trying to write each `datapoint` within the observable collection as an ellipse and draw it to a canvas. The problem is that `X axis` is of `DateTime` and I get the error

> cannot convert DateTime to double

when I use `Canvas.SetLeft(ellipse, Seasonallist[i].X);`.

I don't want to use any third party libraries to do this, should i look into Converters?

```
Seasonallist = new ObservableCollection<DataPoint>();

if (Seasonallist != null)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= Seasonallist.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        Ellipse ellipse = new Ellipse();
        ellipse.Width = 5;
        ellipse.Height = 5; 
        ellipse.Fill = Brushes.Blue;
        Canvas.SetLeft(ellipse, Seasonallist[i].X); <--error here
        Canvas.SetTop(ellipse, Seasonallist.Y);    
        textCanvas.Children.Add(ellipse);
    }
}

public class DataPoint
{
   public DateTime X { get; set; }
   public double Y { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try the `Ticks` Property of the `DataTime`.

```
Canvas.SetLeft(ellipse, Convert.ToDouble(Seasonallist[i].X.Ticks));
```

you have to find a good way to convert this big number into X Canvas coordination.

Comment: okay, i have used the Ticks property, but it is giving a really huge number like Seasonallist[i].X.Ticks = 635241312000000000, can i just arbitrary divide that large number by some other number to reduce it to a smaller number ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will need to use a converter but first you must determine the width of a time interval. This is best done using the ticks values so:

TicksPerPixel is Display duration / Display Width

You can then store this value and use formula DateTime.Ticks /  TicksPerPixel to calculate the left property needed to draw it in the correct location.